# The replicator equation vs the Lotka-Volterra equation

Tags: evolution, ecology, natural-selection, theoretical-biology, evolutionary-game-theory

**Background**

The replicator equation with $n$ strategies is given by the differential equation:
\begin{equation}
  \dot x_{i} = x_{i} \left( \sum_{j=1}^{n} a_{ij}x_{j} - \phi \right)
  \qquad i = 1, \ldots, n
\end{equation}
where $x_i$ is the frequency of the strategy $i$, $A=[a_{ij}]$ is the payoff matrix, and $\phi$ is the average fitness of the population. Basically, what the replicator equation is saying is that the rate of increase of the strategy $i$ (i.e., $\dot x_i/ x_i$) is the difference between the fitness of $i$ (i.e., $\sum_{j=1}^{n} a_{ij}x_{j}$) and the average fitness $\phi$ of the whole population.

The Lotka-Volterra equation with $n-1$ species is:
\begin{equation}
  \dot y_{i} = y_{i} \left(r_{i} + \sum_{j=1}^{n-1} b_{ij}y_{j}\right) \qquad
  i=1, \ldots , n-1
\end{equation}
where $y_i$ is the abundance of species $i$, $r_i$ the intrinsic growth rate, and $b_{ij}$ describes how the species $i$ and $j$ interact ([wiki entry on the Lotka-Volterra eqn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_Lotka%E2%80%93Volterra_equation)).

According to Nowak's book *Evolutionary Dynamics*, these two equations are equivalent to each other (the same result appears in Hofbauer and Sigmund's *Evolutionary Games and Population Dynamics*). This is a neat result because it shows that results in ecology based on the Lotka-Volterra equation has a game theoretic interpretation and vice-versa.

**Question**

This would mean that the replicator equation for **two** strategies (e.g., the Hawk-Dove game) is equivalent to a **single** species interacting with itself under the Lotka-Volterra equation. How could that be? The replicator equation would describe the frequency of two strategies in the population, but the equivalent Lotka-Volterra equation would describe the evolution of a single and undifferentiated population. My problem is not so much with the proof of the equivalence between these two equations (Hofbauer and Sigmund give a proof of this equivalence in their book), but with the interpretation of the equivalence between the two eqns.

Comment: Can you please define all the parameters in both equations?

Comment: Sorry. I've just added a description of the parameters.

Comment: It'd be great if one could already prove this equaltiy between the two models. Did M. Nowak referenced his claim? Do you have references also for the replicator and the Lotka-Volterra equations? The L-V equation seems a little weird to me. It doesn't quite match with what I found on [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Competitive_Lotka%E2%80%93Volterra_equations). Also, it feels weird to talk about $n-1$ species, rather than replacing all the $n-1$, by $n$ in the equation and make it valid for $n$ species. +1

Comment: Nowak refers to this result in his "Evolutionary Dynamics" but the proof appears in Hofbauer & Sigmund's "Evolutionary Games and Population Dynamics." Regarding the L-V equation, my understanding is that Nowak is referring to the generalized version of this eqn rather than the one used to study competition between species. I could follow the proof but, like you, I still find it very weird that we are mapping a game theoretic model with $n$ strategies to a L-V equation with $n-1$ species. It's one of those cases in which you understand the math but you cannot quite understand what is going on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key point is that the first equation is describing *frequencies*, i.e., $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i = 1$, so there are only $n-1$ degrees of freedom. For instance, if $n=2$ (as in Hawk-Dove), you can totally describe the state of the system with just $x_1$, because $x_2$ is just $x_2=1-x_1$. This constraint is enforced by adjusting $\phi$.

To convert the Lotka-Volterra model to the first equation, define $x_i\equiv y_i/\sum_j y_j$.